# working with c++11 lambda codes

Tags: c++11, lambda

C++ with its new features seems to be a new language for those who write old fashion codes. Consider this function

```
template<typename Type>
void Sequitur<Type>::printList(const Symbol * list, unsigned int number) const 
{
    list->forUntil([&number, this](const Symbol * item) {
        if(typeid(*item) == ValueType) {
          fout << static_cast<const Value*>(item)->getValue() << " ";
        }
        if(!--number) 
          return false;
        else 
          return true;
    });
}
```

This inline function is defined in a so called `tpp` file

```
template<typename Child>
template<typename Function> const Child * BaseList<Child>::forUntil(const Function & f) const
{
  const BaseList * item = this;
  const BaseList * next;
  while(item) {
    next = item->next_ptr;
    if(!f(static_cast<const Child*>(item))) 
      break;
    item = next;
  }
  return static_cast<const Child*>(item);
}
```

Assume everything is defined since the code is working. What I want to do is to add a counter to count how many time the `while` is executed. The counter value should be available at the end of `printList()`.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has not much to do with lambdas. If you'd like to get the number of iterations, instead of overly complicating your code, change the return type of `forUntil` to `std::pair<const Child*, std::size_t>`, where `retval.second` is the iteration count.

On the other hand, if you need how many times the functor has been called, you can track it yourself:

```
template<typename Type>
void Sequitur<Type>::printList(const Symbol * list, unsigned int number) const 
{
    std::size_t fCallNum = 0;

    list->forUntil([&](const Symbol * item) {
        ++fCallNum;
        if(typeid(*item) == ValueType) {
          fout << static_cast<const Value*>(item)->getValue() << " ";
        }
        if(!--number) 
          return false;
        else 
          return true;
    });

    std::cout << "Functor called " << fCallNum << " times\n";
}
```

In your particular case, these the two counters would result in the same value, however, they are semantically different.